# Alternative to Fisher's exact test with swapped H1 and H0

Tags: hypothesis-testing, fishers-exact-test

Is there an alternative to the Fishers's exact test that has as null hypothesis that the relative proportions of one variable are **dependent** of the second variable?

Comment: I would be surprised if there are: The usual practice is to have a 'simple' null hypothesis (no association, pop mean 100, 2 pop means equal, and so on). The null hypothesis $H_0$ provides **a** probability distribution, and marked divergence from that dist'n leads to rejection of $H_0.$ If you're talking about 'dependent', then there are _degrees_ of dependency to be considered. // Why not explain your data and objective. There might be a way to look at your situation so that you can use Fisher's exact test.

Comment: @BruceET, if you look at the example here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fisher_exact.html I compute the p-value with as matrix [[1278,209],[1244,243]]. The p-value I get is 0.0918 therefore I cannot reject the null hypothesis of whales and sharks not having a preference for a given ocean. What I would like to do instead is to have as null hypothesis that whales and sharks do have a preference for an ocean and test whether I can reject it or not.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what you are trying to accomplish with that. And as i explained in my previous comment, this is not a useful kind of test.

Comment: There is much good material about this situation in our [answers that mention "TOST"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=TOST%20score%3a2%20is%3aanswer).  Check it out!